# Custom Accessors For Bool Values

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

`Task` is `NSManagedObject` descendant. It has an ivar `checked`. `checked` is type of `NSNumber` which wraps a `BOOL` value.

Working access:

```
BOOL chcecked = [task.checked boolValue];
task.checked = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

But I want somethink like this:

```
BOOL checked = task.checked;
task.checked = YES;
```

So I did category with primitive accessors:

```
@interface Task (PrimitiveAccessors)

- (void)setChecked:(BOOL)checked;
- (BOOL)checked;

@end


@implementation Task (PrimitiveAccessors)

- (void)setChecked:(BOOL)checked
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"checked"];
    self.checked = [NSNumber numberWithBool:checked];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"checked"];
}

- (BOOL)checked
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"checked"];
    BOOL returnValue = [self.checked boolValue];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"checked"];
    return returnValue;
}

@end
```

But it does not work... I tried `BOOL checked = task.checked;` and also `BOOL chcecked = [task checked];`. It still crashes. What is wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.checked` is equivalent to  `[self checked]`.  So `-(BOOL)checked` is getting stuck in an infinite loop calling itself.

The benefit of using NSNumber * accessors instead of primitive ones is that you can determine if the property has been set to true or false, or hasn't been set at all.  In this case it may not matter, but in general it can be useful information to know.

Core Data dynamically generates accessors for you, so I would recommend something like:

```
@interface Task : NSManagedObject
{}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * checked;

- (BOOL) taskIsChecked;
- (void) setTaskIsChecked:(BOOL)isChecked;

@end

@implementation Task
@dynamic checked;

- (BOOL) taskIsChecked
{
  return [self.checked boolValue];
}

- (void) setTaskIsChecked:(BOOL)isChecked
{
  self.checked = isChecked ? (NSNumber *)kCFBooleanTrue : (NSNumber *)kCFBooleanFalse;
}


@end
```

Comment: Well... I hoped It'll override autogenerated accessors. Your solution is not as sweet as I wanted, but if this is only way, than thank you!

Comment: You could probably just use your code as-as, but substitute `[self primitiveChecked]` where you're using `self.checked` and it should work just fine.  I just don't like overriding the auto-accessors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to create primitive accessors, but custom accessors. However you should also declare primitive accessors. Even though it would work with `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:`, according to Apples documentation primitive accessors are a lot faster than KVC.

In your Task.h file declare:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL checked;
```

In your implementation declare the primitive accessor methods:

```
@interface Task (PrimitiveAccessors)
- (void)setPrimitveChecked:(NSNumber *)value;
- (NSNumber *)primitiveChecked;
@end
```

Finally implement the custom accessor methods:

```
- (void)setChecked:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"checked"];
    [self setPrimitiveChecked:[NSNumber numberWithBool:flag]];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"checked"];
}

- (BOOL)checked
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"checked"];
    flag = [[self primitiveChecked] boolValue];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"checked"];

    return flag;
}
```

You can now access and set your *checked* property as a boolean.